# Can this expression be simplified any further with the Laws of logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am currently on this Discrete math question and so far I have done a majority of the solving, but I am unsure if I am doing the steps right. Can someone give me some advice or explanations for the parts I did wrong? Note that it is one equation connected by the conjunction sign. All i did was split it for easier managing. [image]

Comment: Keep going. What happens if you and the left term with the two or'd expressions? Also, your outer brackets on the right side disappeared and they shouldn't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you distribute the $ \neg q \vee p $, then the $ \neg q $ cancels with the $q \wedge (p \vee r)$ and the $p $ cancels with the $\neg p \wedge r$, so we are left with.

$ (\neg q \wedge \neg p \wedge r) \vee (p\wedge q \wedge (p \vee r)) $ which is equivalent to $ (\neg q \wedge \neg p \wedge r) \vee (p \wedge q )$

Comment: ahhh, DARN, I can't believe I didnt see that step.. thank you!